# How to convert n rows into a single row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert rows in a table to a single row - the old pivot chestnut. I'm using sqlserver (and a newbie) and have created a simple example to illustrate the problem.

```
create table myrows (id number, name varchar2(10), seq number);

insert into myrows values (1, 'ACE0316', 1);
insert into myrows values (2, 'ACE3134', 2);
insert into myrows values (3, 'ACE0356', 3);
```

If I submit the following query I get zero results because there's no row with 4 as the seq but I want a **d_name** column regardless of whether there's a row with seq = 4 or not.

```
select a.name a_name, b.name b_name, c.name c_name, d.name d_name
from (
select name from myrows where seq = 1) a,
(select name from myrows where seq = 2) b,
(select name from myrows where seq = 3) c,
(select name from myrows where seq = 4) d
```

Thanks in advance 
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function, `MAX` or `MIN` with `CASE WHEN`

```
create table myrows (id int, name varchar(10), seq int);

insert into myrows values (1, 'ACE0316', 1);
insert into myrows values (2, 'ACE3134', 2);
insert into myrows values (3, 'ACE0356', 3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
    MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 1 then name end) a_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 2 then name end) b_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 3 then name end) c_name
from myrows
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7100/2/0)**:

```
|  a_name |  b_name |  c_name |
|---------|---------|---------|
| ACE0316 | ACE3134 | ACE0356 |
```

Comment: With the addition of `max(case when m.seq = 4 then m.name else null end) as d_name` to account for the (currently) empty column.